# Maximize function in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, maximize

I followed [an example](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3) about a Genetic Algorithm in Java. Although I understand the concept of this application, I do not understand how I would apply a formula of my choice and let the Genetic Algorithm find it's highest value with `x` (an Individual' gene).

I tried the following code, by having the fitness return the value of the formula as followed:

```
static int getFitness(Individual individual) {
    int fitness = 0;

    Integer x = Integer.parseInt(individual.toString(), 2);
    fitness = calculateFormula(x);

    return fitness;
}

public static int calculateFormula(int x) {
   int result = (-x * x) + (7 * x);

   return result;
}
```

But with the tutorial I followed, you are supposed to specify a solution at the beginning. But when I do this, it is going to search for that solution and not the value of `x` that will return the highest `result`. By not specifying a solution, it will just end when it has found the gene representing `0`.

So the question:
How would I apply a formula to the Genetic Algorithm, so it will look for the highest result of the formula `-x² + 7x`?

Comment: "specify a solution at the beginning" - what does this mean? At the beginning of what?

Comment: @KevinHooke [The tutorial](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/creating-a-genetic-algorithm-for-beginners/3) I followed uses a candidate solution at the beginning of the program. The program stops when it has found that candidate. I like to have the Genetic Algorithm to stop when it has found the maximum result of the formula or when the maximum iteration has been reached.

Comment: Re. "stop  when it has found the maximum result" - where is your code being invoked from? You don't have any iteration in your code as shown, so is something else invoking your code in a loop? Where is the logic for determining the maximum result?

Comment: This is a really annoying function for GA. The value it returns is all over the place, due to wrapping. Inputs that are genetically close to each other are far apart in fitness, which is really bad. FWIW you can easily brute force this and the optima are -1161827623 and 1161827630

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here...this seems more like a calculus problem which is fairly straightforward with a derivative to solve...

Comment: I am supposed to do this with genetic algorithm. I know it is far easier with other approaches. My current code is found [here](https://github.com/tislars/genetic-algorithm), but I only showed the snippet for how I thought I should do it.

Comment: @harold I am only asked to look for the value of x between 0 and 31.

Comment: Ok, it's doable then, the function acts more normal in that region (it wants to be 3.5, so you get 3 and 4 with equal fitness). Your problem sounds vague and more related to the specific framework than to GA's in general.

Comment: @harold It's not really a problem, it is more the not understanding of how to apply genetic algorithm to find the highest value of the formula -x² + 7x, using the binary values of 0 between 31.

Comment: Well as you were already doing, make that the fitness, then "do the evolution thing", which is already in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "specifying a solution" you probably mean the following function in the blog:

```
static int getMaxFitness() {
    int maxFitness = solution.length;
    return maxFitness;
}
```

Which is causing trouble in your case. The dumb solution:

```
static int getMaxFitness() {
    return 12;
}
```

Now the algorithm will find `3` (`00011` you only need 5 bits/genes to check `0` to `31`) or `4` (`00100`) as it is supposed to.

For a more intelligent solution we have to look at the termination criteria:

```
int generationCount = 0;
while(myPop.getFittest().getFitness() < FitnessCalc.getMaxFitness()){
  generationCount++;
  System.out.println("Generation: "+generationCount+" Fittest: "+myPop.getFittest().getFitness());
  myPop = Algorithm.evolvePopulation(myPop);
}
```

You could stop looking for a solution when there was no improvement for X generations:

```
int bestFitness = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Individual bestIndividual = null;
int noImprovementCount = 0;
for (int generationCount = 1;; generationCount++) {
  System.out.println("Generation: "+generationCount+" Fittest: "+myPop.getFittest().getFitness());
  myPop = Algorithm.evolvePopulation(myPop);
  if (bestFitness < myPop.getFittest().getFitness()) {
    bestIndividual = myPop.getFittest();
    bestFitness = bestIndividual.getFitness();
    noImprovementCount = 0;
  } else if (++noImprovementCount == 5) { // X = 5
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I meant with specifying a candidate solution is [this line](https://github.com/TisLars/genetic-algorithm/blob/master/src/Program.java#L12). With your addition to my code, I still need to add this line and tell the Algorithm "00011" is the solution I want to find. Or am I missing something? Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Lars you don't need to set a solution as far as I can see, because you replaced the getFitness function. It is only there to show that with this fitness function (counting the bits that are the same as the solution) the population will indeed evolve towards the candidate solution.

Comment: Such a late response coming from me, sorry. This was indeed perfect! You helped me so much and I could get it to work in my current project.